# How to perform update in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

When I use update statement I get the following response.

update t1 set t1.id=t2.id , t1.name=t2.name ,t1.age=t2.age where t2.id in (select id from t1);

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.

Can anyone provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enables your tables for transactional process, you have to mention this while creating table schema.

You can refer to the website below as in to know how to achieve that.

http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.fr/2014/11/updatedeleteinsert-in-hive-0140.html

Comment: Can't we do update  without setting these properties.  Like using some queries.

Comment: No, you have to define the table schema in the beginning based on the purpose. If you already have a huge data in your table, create another table with same schema ( column names) and adding transnational property. Then copy data using select statement from one table to another. It is a one step process.